# CSS Responsive Issues With Safari max-width: 100% ect

Tags: safari, responsive-design, css

Chrome and FF seem to use my CSS Responsive Styles Correctly

Safari Does not If you go to {a link](173.83.251.7/~grebesba/) in Safari you will see that the middle images do not react properly but if you compare it to chrome and ff it does.

Im lost at this point and it was a challenge to get it to work as far as it has already.

Any sug

Comment: good looking site, btw

Comment: It is a good looking site!  But for posterity could you maybe include a link to a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with a simplified version of the problem?  Sites change over time, this way future visitors can easily see what the problem was.  Trying to replicate the problem on a small scale can also help you yourself identify the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Add explicit percentage widths to your tables td's.  For example, the row with the donut menu image (donut2.jpg) has three td's.  The widths of those td's should be 48.1%, 17.2%, 34.5%, respectively.  ...  got these percentages by dividing the width of the image by the total table width.  Safari does not automatically size the td's according to the size of the image for some reason.

Comment: The issue I'm seeing is that when you shrink your window horizontally, the images loose proportion (ie to tall).  Are we looking at the same issue?

Comment: here is a screen shot of what happens when I use hight auto  173.83.251.7/~grebesba/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/height-auto.jpg

Comment: To hopefully get us on the same page i just put the original code back to were it started before the height auto it appears that safari isnt controlling the actual ratio of 100% properly it does on the final two images at the bottom but not the ones on the top you can see what it should look like in chrome

Comment: Think I got it:  Add explicit percentage widths to your tables td's.  For example, the row with the donut menu image (donut2.jpg) has three td.  The widths of those td's should be 48.1%, 17.2%, 34.5%, respectively.  <td style="width: 48.1%">...  got these percentages by dividing the width of the image by the total table width.

Comment: It worked in safari but created a new issue in FF 173.83.251.7/~grebesba/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/td-with-percentages.jpg

Comment: Tables are really hard to do responsive stuff with.  Honestly, I would abandon the table route and convert it to divs so you can control them easier.

Comment: Is there a php "if statement "that I can use on this page specifically for safari and all others would populate the other? If so do you know how to structure it?